# New git submodule missing everytime I checkout my repo/branch

Tags: git, github, branch, git-submodules

Whenever I clone my repo (`<my_repo>`) locally, the new submodule's directory (under `<my_repo>/_includes/<NEW_submodule_2>`) is empty.

I have added in my `<NEW_submodule_2>/.gitmodules` like so:

```
[submodule "_includes/<submodule_1>"]
    path = _includes/submodule_1
    url = https://github.com/<my_org>/submodule_1
    branch  = master
[submodule "_includes/<NEW_submodule_2>"]
    path = _includes/<NEW_submodule_2>
    url = https://github.com/<my_org>/<NEW_submodule_2>
    branch  = master
```

I have to always run the following to get that directory populated: `git submodule update --init --remote _includes/<NEW_submodule_2>`

How do I fix this so that this command doesn't have to be run everytime I git clone (or whenever someone else clones)?

Comment: You can't fix (?) it for others as Git does not consider this to be an error. As [VonC noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72223296/1256452), you can enable submodule recursion at `git clone` time (and other times: see the `submodule.recurse` setting for instance; note that it does not affect `git clone` but does affect other commands).

Answer (score 0):

You could use one command: [`git clone --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt)

```
git clone --recurse-submodules=_includes/<NEW_submodule_2>
```

But both submodule1 and 2 should be empty after a regular clone.